# Sharing someone else's YouTube video to someone else's public playlist if I have the link?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I am trying to share a video that I made with a teacher's public playlist.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First, your teacher should add you as collaborator of the playlist.
Then (from [Collaborate on playlists - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6109639?hl=en&ref_topic=3030072)):

> ### Contribute videos to a playlist
>
> Once you’ve been invited to contribute
>   to a playlist, you can add videos or remove videos that you added in
>   the past.
>
> #### Add videos
>
> 1. Use the link you got from the playlist owner to go the playlist page.
> 2. Follow the on-screen instructions to confirm that you want to be a contributor. The playlist will be automatically saved.
> 3. To add videos from your computer or a mobile device, use one of these options:
>
>    - On the playlist page, select Add Video and paste in a video URL, choose a video from your uploads, or search for a video on YouTube.
>    - Go to a video you want to add and select the Add to menu from that video.
>
> After you add a video, your name will appear next to the video in the
>   playlist. All collaborators will get a notification when new videos
>   are added to the playlist.